# Where on today's map of India, was the confluence of the Baes and Sutlej rivers when Alexander was in the Punjab?

Tags: ancient-india, alexander-the-great

I am trying to understand where on today's map of the Punjab, Alexander and his armies returned after a mutiny. The historical accounts (Arrian, for example) suggest he reached the Beas River, which is in today's Indian side of the Punjab. According to historical sources, such as Arrian, he built a giant monument to mark the eastern most point of the campaign there.

It is of course possible, that the Beas River in those days ran differently than today.

Assuming that the ancient sources are correct, is anything known about where on today's map the mutiny took place and the monument would have been built?

Comment: Hello! I think the short answer is that we don't know, but I believe someone else can refer you to more specific sources.

Comment: Just so we're all clear on this, in 1998, someone erected [a monument near Jalalpur Sharif](https://tribune.com.pk/story/1644751/1-alexanders-monument-jhelum-dire-straits) where they thought the location was.

Comment: @Spencer: thanks for this. You are referencing a monument near the battlefield where Alexander and Porus clashed, I think. However, after that Alexander marched further east into what today is India. At the Beas River (and probably where the Beas and Sutlej meet), the army mutinied and Alexander was forced to return. Arrian says he built a monument there. I would like to know the present day location of that. Personally I think it would be somewhere south east of Amritsar. But I would like to know of there is any research on it.

Answer (score -1):

My conjecture is the Macedonians used the Uttarpatha (Grand Trunk Road), as they marched SE towards Nanda lands. If this is true, they would have stopped at where the GTR intersects with the Beas. Today that’s at 31°30'46"N 75°18'11"E, but possibly slightly elsewhere depending on where the Beas flowed 2300 years ago

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have plotted your coordinates on Google maps: https://www.google.com/maps/place/31°30'46.0%22N+75°18'11.0%22E/@31.5129232,74.973443,10z/data=!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d31.5127778!4d75.3030556?entry=ttu

Comment: That would indeed be east of Amritsar, as I also suspect. However, the Beas river probably does not run the same way as it did in Alexander's time. So not sure if this is the historical location?

Answer (score -1):

I'm no student of ancient history but there is a town called Alexander Town only 8 hours walk from the stated map point. Sikanderpur , it is between the town rivers as they stand today and is a days walk from each.  31.415816, 75.644223

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I just found that there is a possible descendant group in the village of Malana in Hamachal Pradesh very close to the Beas River, maybe the monument is there or downriver some. I would guess as outsiders they would eventually retreat into the hills north for security.  Indian Scientists are studying their DNA to find a link to Sikander (Alexanders army). Though to be honest, the group I saw around Passu in the N.W. Frontier province of Pakistan looked very Balkan reddish hair blue eyes etc.
32.06123627667215, 77.26053631973647

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: if its just a visual observation then that could also be a genetic marker from more recent times such as the British Empire days